# How to enable ngx-bootstrap tooltip on [innerHTML] from variable

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I can successfully get tooltips working with ngx-bootstrap when I do for example:

```html
<div><button tooltip="Tooltip works!">Button with a Tooltip</button></div>
```

But if I need to set the innerHtml of the div dynamically, say from a variable:

```js
let content = '<button tooltip="This tooltip wont work">Button with a Tooltip</button>';
```

and set the innerHtml as such:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

The tooltip never renders.

I'm assuming I need to do something else, but I cannot find an answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever work this out Jeremiah?

Answer (score 0):

InnerHTML example, which has the html within the innerHTML, however you can use a variable if you want:

```
<ng-template #content>
  <div [innerHTML]=“‘<div>Button with a        Tooltip</div>’”>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<div><button [tooltip]="content" placement=“top”></button></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use it like below:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  content;
  newvalue:string ='<strong>Stackoverflow</strong> is <em>helpful!</em>';
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<button style="border:1px solid #3333">Button with a Tooltip</button>')
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jftbrm

If you use like

`let content = '';` This you cant use it inside template.

Comment: This achieved the same result with no tooltip. Upon further inspection, it seems that all of the HTML is being stripped from the string before being set ass the innerHTML.

Comment: This does not work - stackblitz appears non-functional